# pass toString(number) in innerHTML

Tags: javascript

This is my first post, I am "new" to javascript but experienced in actionscript. I'm having an issue that should not be one, can't get my head around it.

In the code below all I want to do is pass a integer variable (stackID) as an img id attribute inside innerHTML. It must be some detail I just don't know but I have searched for hours on google to no avail. Help would be greatly aprreciated. Whatever I do, it seems I can only pass `<img id="string">`, which of course is not what I want. Can't pass `<img id=numVariable>`, or `<img id=String(numVariable)>`,    there must surely be a way to do this ?

Thanks folks !

Here is the line of code :

```
div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id=String(stackID) onclick="close(this.id)">';
```

Comment: We can't post code ? Trying again :
innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id=String(stackID) onclick="close(this.id)">';

Comment: I don't get it, code was removed from original post. Here it is again from the last sentence :

Whatever I do, it seems I can only pass id="string" , which of course is not what I want. Can't pass id=numVariable , or id=String(numVariable), there must surely be a way to do this ? 

Here is the line of code = 

var stackIDString = String(stackID);

div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id=stackIDString  onclick="close(this.id)">';

Comment: Ok comments have all breaks removed. Hm. Will try somewhere else it's safe to say there are some rules I'm not aware of here, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass it in the string.
What you want to do is:

```
div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id="' + String(stackID) + '" onclick="close(' + this.id + ')">';
```

Oh and since you're already making a string, you don't need the String() convert, you can just `id="' + stackID + '"`

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is loosely typed and will automatically convert (to the best of its abilities) anything you want to interpolate in a string:

```
var num = 1;
"sup" + num; // => "sup1"
```

It's cool, but be careful though, it can lead to some weird surprises:

```
var obj = {};
"sup" + obj.missingKey; //  => "supundefined"
```

In that case, `obj.missingKey === undefined`, and `String(undefined) === "undefined"`, so `"sup" + obj.missingKey` becomes in fact `"sup" + "undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

javascript has not string interpolation. Concatenate *stackId* like:

```
div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id="' + stackID + '" onclick="close(this.id)">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '+' to join chunks like this:

```
 div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id="' + String(stackID) + '" onclick="close(' + this.id + ')">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you make the variable is dynamic:

```
    var x = 0;
    x = x +1;
    div.innerHTML='<img src="img/xbut.png" id="name_' + x + '" onclick="close(this.id)">';
```